# mobile fast click - prevent ghost focus

Tags: jquery, mobile

I'm doing fast click for mobile browser. When I fast click on link of current page, it does an ajax load to next page. My fast click script can stop the ghost click now. But if there is an input element on next page at click position on current page, it still get a focus and display virtual keyboard. How to prevent ghost focus event too?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your click handler, the page you are loading is setting its focus to input, you have to remove that script on that page.

Answer (score 10):

To prevent actions related to an event, use `.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `preventDefault()`.

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mJXnL/)

> - [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/) - Handlers within the same function where it is call, will be executed normally, but will immediately neglect/stop any actions within other functions related to the same event. For example:

```
// alert will fire
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(event) {
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
 alert('Hello world');
});

// but this will be stopped
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(event) {
 console.log('I am stopped!');
});
```

---

> - [preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) - When called, default action will be neglected. For example

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="foo">Google it!</a>
```

The link will be halted, but an alert will fire

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 alert('I prefer MSN');
});
```

Both should be combined together in order to stop events from bubbling up the DOM tree.

I made a [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mJXnL/) to explain the differences between both and why both should be combined together.

Based on the above, your code should look like this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector', function (event) {
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the write up, this is very helpful, the bounty is yours pal.

Comment: @JoaoFerreira Thank you. I'm glad I've been of help :)

Comment: This works for the 'click' action, but when I tried with 'touchstart' or 'touchend' it doesn't work. The 'click' action with the above code produces some 300ms delay when you click the button, which makes the app feel slow.

Comment: @willdanceforfun try `.on("touchstart touchend", function` combined together.

Comment: @Omar actually I had not tried both together, but I have now, and unfortunately it still doesn't work. I tried 'click' again and it works. Does stopImmediatePropagation and preventDefault work for touch actions?

Comment: @willdanceforfun yes they do work. Have you tried them on a different platform other than android?

Comment: @Omar I have only tried android 4.3. I will try on iOs but getting my hands on a phone is a bit tricky. I just need it to work on android though. Seems weird that click works but not touchstart and touchend.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using fastclick.js. Here's my way to prevent auto trigger on next page:

Global CSS:

```
#preventClick { width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1000; top:0; left:0; }
```

HTML on next page:

```
<body>
    <div id="preventClick"></div>
    <!-- button on the same coordinate with previous page -->
</body>
```

Script on next page:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#preventClick').hide(); }, 300);
}
```

300 is the minimum and no point putting more than that

Answer (score -1):

I've been struggeling with this for a little while now, but only found a partial solution. Although I think it's good enough for my problem. Hopefully it will also be helpful to someone else.

This solution is based on jQuery mobile, but you might be able to do something similar if you don't use that.

What I do is, I place an empty div that fills the entire screen on top of other elements, so that it blocks (most) click/touch events.

```
<div id="ghostBuster" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:9999;display:none;"></div>
```

I show it before I hide the page I'm changing from.

```
$("div[data-role='page']").on("pagebeforehide", function() {
     $("#ghostBuster").show();
});
```

And hide it again once the next page is shown.

```
$("div[data-role='page']").on("pageshow", function() {
    $("#ghostBuster").hide();
});
```

I've not tested it very thoroughly and only on my android device, but so far it seems to work for avoiding ghost clicks and focussing. It doesn't work for avoiding ghost clicking select boxes. And it doesn't work when the transition animation between the pages is very fast. I've solved the problem with select boxes by switching to the non-native alternative that jQuery mobile provides.

You might consider hiding the div again on mouseup, but that doesn't work in my case as I use swipes to change pages.

It's probably not the prettiest possible solution, but so far I've been unable to find or come up with a better one.

Comment: I was hopeful this would work, but it doesn't work on my phone with Android 4.3.1.