# jQuery Mobile changePage in pagebeforeshow Flicker

Tags: jquery-mobile

In several of my jQuery Mobile pages, I need to ensure that certain variables are set before allowing the page to show. As such, I check for these variables in the `pagebeforeshow` event and if they are not present or correct, I call the `$.mobile.changePage(...)` inside the `pagebeforeshow` event and then immediately return.

In jQuery Mobile 1.2.1 this seemed to work perfectly. However, now that I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 I've noticed an odd rendering issue. Now when I call the changePage inside the `pagebeforeshow` event, it causes jQuery Mobile to transition to the page I requested, then back to the original page, firing the `pageshow` event, and then finally transitions back to the page I did the changePage to.

While not a major issue, it is a inconvenience and causes unnecessary transitions. Has anyone else encountered this issue and if so, have you been able to prevent the unnecessary transitions and event firing? Thanks!

Example Code:

```js
$('#ConditionalPage').on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    if (!someScopedVariable) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#RegularPage');
        return;
    }
}

$('#ConditionalPage').on('pageshow', function () {
    ... \\ Code that gets fired even though pagebeforeshow called changePage.
}
```

Comment: try `pagebeforechange` also you can use `preventDefault()` and `stopImmediatePropagation()` to ensure that any function related to a certain `.selector` won't trigger. check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064418/mobile-fast-click-prevent-ghost-focus) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunate the `pagebeforechange` didn't seem to help, nor did adding the `preventDefault` and the `stopImmediatePropagation` to that event or my existing events.

Comment: Hmmm.. Try this `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow','#ConditionalPage', function()....etc`

Comment: Technically, that is what I do. I create a scoped variable for `$(document)` into `$document`, and then do all my binding that way via `$document.on('pagebeforeshow', pageSelector, function() {...})`, and repeat for all my page events.

Comment: Try adding `.off('pageshow`)` before `.on()`.

Comment: Why would I remove events from an element when no prior events of that type have been bound to the element? It's not a matter of bound events. It's the fact that in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 it seems that calling a `changePage` while in a page event does not stop the current page from completing it's page event lifecycle, while previously it did.

Comment: Sometimes events trigger twice, this to make sure it doesn't.

Comment: An event would trigger twice if it was registered twice. I can easily and have confirmed that events are only registered once. Also, if that was -really- the case I would see my breakpoints being hit twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I changed page from one page to another it went fine. But when I changed back with:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#frontPage");
```

the page shifted a few times between the two pages.

The problem was solved by moving some functionality I had defined in:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {...})
```

into:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '[data-role=page]', function () {...})
```