# CSS :hover state gets stuck on IOS devices when clicking to hide/show content

Tags: jquery, css, ipad, ios7, hover

Very simple problem here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EhAIs

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="top">Top</a>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-wrap">
        <a href="#" class="bottom">Bottom</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I have a click event set on `.top` that hides `.top-wrap` and shows `.bottom-wrap`. `.bottom`'s hover state is stuck on when it shows (darkblue in the jsfiddle, should be lightblue). This is on iPad and iPhone 5 so far in IOS7.

I can't find an answer here to this, I've searched quite a bit. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the codepen link, when I click on top, everything just disappears on desktop... is this supposed to happen? I added preventDefault http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jcHIG

Comment: When I click the link in codepen in desktop, the bottom-wrap div shows, which should be darkblue because it's still hovered. But it should be lightblue on IOS because it's not hovered, yet it still shows up dark blue. Is this not what you're seeing?

Comment: Looks like a ghost click issue since you are binding click

Comment: you can try what is suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064418/mobile-fast-click-prevent-ghost-focus but on my simulator, it does not work. You might need to bind to touch events to prevent this from happening

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately, even when I added in preventDefault on a touchstart event.